# MongoDB recieves empty post requests (express.js + mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having a following issue:

I try to post data to my MongoDB cluster via express app. I'm using mongoose for object modelling. The trouble is whatever the body of my post request is, mongoose doesn't read the data from the request properly.

Model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

// Schema for one poll completion

const answersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: String,
    age: Number,
    choices: [Number]
});

const Answer = mongoose.model('Answer', answersSchema);

export default Answer;
```

Controller

```
import Answer from '../models/answers.model.js'


export const postAnswers = async (req,res) => {
    const answer = req.body;
    console.log(`Created an answer list: ${{ answer } }`);
    const newAnswer = new Answer(answer)
    console.log( newAnswer );
    try { 
        await newAnswer.save((err) => {if (err) return console.error(err)});
        res.status(201).json(newAnswer);
        console.log('new answer recieved!');

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(409).json({message: error.message});
        console.log('failed posting answers');
    }
}
```

Example:

I send a following request using postman:

```
{
    "user": "Krzysztof",
    "age": "15",
    "choices": ["1","2","3"]
}
```

The log from controller is the following:

```
Created an answer list: [object Object]
{ choices: [], _id: 608fd21941efba10b41469db }
new answer recieved!
```

The app returns a 201, but `newAnswer` document derived from `Answer` models is always empty.

I'm just starting out with writing back-end functionality and APIs, I'd welcome any suggestions as how to debug such apps properly in Node. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show result of `console.log(answer);`?

Comment: It's an empty object. I figured it out. I didn't include Content-type: application/json in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out:

I didn't add a `Content-type: application/json` header in my requests and the controlled recieved an empty object.